MVC .NET Core Localization Dynamic
I have added a multi-language option to my site using MVC .NET Core localization. However, I believe this will be problematic in the dynamic areas of the site. I don't want to resort to file structures like "en/Index" or "fr/Index". How can I make the data in SharedResources.resx dynamic? Is there a way to convert data from a database back to Resx without impacting site performance and without unnecessary file structuring? I am seeking your support to advance the architecture effectively. Thank you in advance.
........................

Hi @Eray Genç, for how to use SharedResources, you need check this answer. For your second question, did you mean you store the key and value in database and you want to convert the record in database to resource file? How is your table like in database?

.resx files are compiled and can not be dynamic! each update to the .resx file will need you to recompile the app to take effect. Converting data from db to resx for localization is not the correct way, you need to find another solution. e.g. see this answer
